# GetComponents Error Unity : Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

The error : **InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.**

appears when I use this piece of code:

```
var PolyCol : PolygonCollider2D[];

function Start(){
    PolyCol = GetComponents(PolygonCollider2D);
}
```

The gameobject with this code on it has 5 PolygonCollider2D attached to it.

Any ideas on why this error is appearing??

And can you explain what this means to me? :)

Comment: Solved: GetComponents returns Component[], not PolygonCollider2D[]; the error means that you can't convert from one to the other. (Which, yes, makes it inconsistent with GetComponent, which returns Type rather than Component.) You can use the generic version: GetComponents.< PolygonCollider2D >().

Comment: You should answer your own question so that people know it is solved. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: 
GetComponents returns Component[], not PolygonCollider2D[]; the error means that you can't convert from one to the other. (Which, yes, makes it inconsistent with GetComponent, which returns Type rather than Component.)

You can use the generic version: GetComponents.< PolygonCollider2D >().